# How to select empty paths with POSTGRES LTREE

Tags: postgresql, ltree

I have a simple table defined in Postgres, where I'm using LTREE, but some rows can have empty paths:

```
CREATE TABLE films (
    id     serial PRIMARY KEY,
    title  varchar(40) NOT NULL,
    path   ltree DEFAULT NULL 
);
```

If I insert the following values into the table,

```
INSERT INTO films (title, path)
VALUES ('first', 'A'),('second', 'A.B'),('third', NULL);
```

then try to select the rows with empty paths,

```
SELECT * FROM films WHERE path=NULL;
```

I get empty rows:

```
 id | title | path 
----+-------+------
(0 rows)
```

How should I modify the query to return rows with empty paths? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result of comparison operation with at least one operand is  NULL always returns NULL. Thus your predicate `where path = null` always returns null, but the to select a row the expression must return True.  Use instead:

```
SELECT * FROM films WHERE path is NULL;
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply! I'm sorry, but I don't see how your query is different from the one I posted in the question.

Comment: Sorry, cut / paste error. See Revised.